# Editing checkout field woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

On my WooCommerce checkout page, the County field is required, but it gets autofilled by Woo with a random value and some clients forget to put their own county.

[image]

How can i edit that checkout field to a have a placeholder or a first value that says Choose your option like in the picture below. And if possible to warn the customer and remind them to pick something if they forget and checkout with that first value.

[image]

I played with some code in function.php in the child theme, with woo filters but got no luck. I use woodmart premium theme if that helps.

Comment: Its my third time posting this question. I dont know how else to ask it. I hope its more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding this code to your child theme function.php file.

```
add_filter( 'default_checkout_billing_state', 'change_default_checkout_state' 
);
add_filter( 'default_checkout_shipping_state', 
'change_default_checkout_state' );

function change_default_checkout_state() {
    return 'Select a county'; 
}
```

If you want to warn the customer you could try this..

```
//Hook
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'fields_before_order_details');

//function

function fields_before_order_details(){
echo 'Don't forget to add your county.';
}
```

Comment: For the country i have selected only 1 country in wich they can get shipping. Problem for me is the "county", is like a region inside a country. They have to select it, but when woo covers that for them with a random choice they often forget to put their own county and for them to get their order its complicated.

Comment: Sorry about that, I need to check my eyes. I'll have another look later.

Comment: Ok, but they closed my question again...They associated my question to others but thats not the case

Comment: Ok I made an amendment to the code.

Comment: It doesnt change anything. Still a random state.

Comment: I've edited my answer so you can give that a go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229930/discussion-between-joshiewahwah-and-catalin).